# How to build the SOLR query similar to this SQL query?

Tags: solr

I am not sure how to group the ORs and manage the AND in SOLR query. Also how to manage the multiple order fields?

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
WHERE STATE_NAME LIKE '%Gujarat%' 
AND (DESCRIPTION like '%Victory%' OR KEYWORDS like '%Victory%')
ORDER BY RATING, WEIGHT;
```

Please give me some suggestion on how to manage this SQL query in SOLR. I already have the SOLR schema exactly like the SQL Database and I have added all data in SOLR from DB Server.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the type of the fields (I'll assume StrFields), the first should be:

```
q=STATE_NAME:*Gujarat* AND (DESCRIPTION:*Victory* OR Keywords:*Victory*)
```

While the sort would be:

```
sort=RATING, WEIGHT
```